# My correct MySQL query that is supposed to return 4 images, returns only 3

Tags: php, mysql

Even though it works correctly when I query it in phpMyAdmin SQL tab. What I am trying to accomplish is to display all images uploaded by the user ( which are currently 4 ) but I only get 3 ( the one missing is always the first one ). Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $currentUser = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$currentUser'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $author = $getResult['username'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE author='$author' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="profilePageImages" src="uploads/'.$row['path'].'" alt="Random image" /></a>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Remove this statement, `$getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);`. With this you're already fetching one row from the result set, so `while()` loop will start from the 2nd row.

Comment: Have you tried dumping parts of this script?

Comment: Parameterize your query, this is open to injections. You also can do this with 1 query, look at `join`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line, before the loop is consuming the first row. Just delete it.

```
$getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
```